# How to set an background picture for an IME?

Tags: android, background, ime, android-keypad

I would like to know how to display an image behind the keys. I have tried it like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
</ImageView>

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="50%p" >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" 
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

I know that there is some basic stuff missing like the image on the key (and at least 25 other keys), but I just wanted to show you an example.

TL;DR (although this is not a very long post): I want to have an image in the background and a usual keyboard in the foreground.

Thanks in advance :)

Update: I tried this now:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="1%p"
    android:horizontalGap="20px"
    android:verticalGap="300px"
    android:keyHeight="1%p"
    android:background="@drawable/example" 
    >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" 
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"></Key>
        <Key android:codes="113" 
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"></Key>

    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" 
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"></Key>
        <Key android:codes="113" 
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"></Key>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

Did not work :( The xml is properly set, because it displays some sort of keyboard, but the background is just black.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`KeyboardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) object. It extends `View`, so you can use the regular `android:background` attribute to do what you're after. Then, attach your `Keyboard` with `setKeyboard()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and will be back if it does not work :) Unfortunately I cant upvote your comment :/

Comment: Well, you didn't really try what I said. You're not using a `KeyboardView` object at all, just the same `Keyboard`. Have you read the [Developer Guide for Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) yet? If not, you should.